# Symfony 2.3 messages to user saved as resource yml file

Tags: symfony

Is there a way in Symfony 2.3 to use messages loaded from yml file?

Example: CRUD controllers echo a message just for having an entity created or not as `Entity created.`.

Is there a way to define this string in a yml file and use it for every CRUD controller / Twig template and define it once and not to write it for every crud?

Explaining with a better example:

When an entity is created:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success-close', 'Entity created.');
```

But I just like to use ***something*** like this:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success-close', $str_entity_created);
```

where `$str_entity_creted` is defined in a hypothetic `messages.yml`file

```
#MyBundle/Resources/messages.yml
messages:
  str_entity_created: "Entity created."
  ...
  ....
```

So, for every CRUD I have to change the string in just one place and it has changed globally in my entire app, instead of changing every string in every CRUD Controller.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

If I have to load a yml resource globally, how much will it degrade memory consumption and performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#basic-translation)

```
$translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('Symfony2 is great');
```

messages.fr.yml

```
Symfony2 is great: J'aime Symfony2
```

Comment: It is not the answer for my question at all. Yeah, I know about translations, but in my wanted use case: 

The string 'Symfony2 is great' is loaded from a yml file as a "global Resource". 

It's in a way similar to translator resource, but for the MAIN (ROOT) LANGUAGE, I wish to do the same as a translator resources file xliff. Using a global identifier for the string.